# Div arrangement problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

all

I am creating my menu list in footer dynamically.
now in one row max 3 div can be possible then next 4th div will be set under first.
My problem is now the above 3 div has different height. while creating the  2nd row its take the 1st row max height.

see the image you will more clear what i want

[image]

Comment: How do you make this effect? Possibly using floats should work properly. If not, consider rearranging the array of items to be able to make 3 columns of lists.

Comment: ys , i am thinking about the flex layout of html5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is an option to solve this, though possibly overkill for your reasonably simple situation.

Is the width of that brown box fluid or fixed?

Comment: i think this is the good solution let me take loot at this thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of laying out the divs rowwise lay them columnwise.
Have 3 container divs representing columns then place content divs inside these column divs as appropriate.

The table equivalent would be - outer container table having one row and three cells. Each cell would have single column, multi row table.

Comment: i am fetching all data from one loop only. if i want to display it in column wise i need to take 3 for loop. i can't